# Wrapping up factory methods

Tags: c++

I have 2 `structs` whose constructors accept different numbers and types of parameters passed in.
For example,

```
struct A:Base
{
   A(int i, char c){}
};

struct B:Base
{
   B(char c){}
};
```

And I also have a factory method to create these 2 `structs`'s objects,

```
struct F
{
   Base* Do(int i)
   {
      if (i==0)
      {
         return new A(i,'c');
      }
      else
      {
         return new B('c'); 
      }
   }  
};
```

Now that I try to improve my `Factory F` like this

```
struct F
{
   template<int i, class X>
   Base* Do();
   template<class X>
   Base* Do<0>()
   {
      return new X(i, 'c');
   }
   template<class X>
   Base* Do<1>()
   {
      return new X('c');
   }
};
```

The only thing I am not interested in this method is that I have to write a lot of specialized templates in case I have plenty of structs `A,B,C,...` but I only love templates and I don't like `return new X(...)`.

So my questions are:

1. How can I minimize the long code but still use templates ?
2. How can I  stop  returning a pointer to the base class ? Dynamic allocation sux, I prefer slow and tender classic allocators on the stack for my factory.
3. I like to use variadic templates for the arguments of my `structs`' ctors.

Comment: If you actually made a wrapper, like you said in the question title, then #1 is answered somewhat

Comment: why use a templated function instead of just named functions?

Comment: Because I like it and also it is what I don't know how to create and use.

Comment: so something like `template <class T, class... Args> T create(Args args...) { return T(args..., 'c'); }`? called like `.create<A>(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::any` and variadic templates will be your friend. Yuu can store anything in `std::any`. The `any_cast` will be a bit of a problem.

See the following working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```